# check which div accepts the droppable jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My droppable div can be accepted by two classes. Let it be A and B . I want to check which class accepts my droppable and perform some task. i.e, if class A accepts the div, i want to do some task and some other task if it is B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI does not provide an easy way to obtain the dropzone using the `drop` event.

I would perhaps try something like this:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $dropzone = $(this).parent();

        if( $dropzone.hasClass('classA') )
        {
            // Handle .classA
        }
        else
        {
           // Handle .classB
        }
    },
});
```

Of course, this assumes that the dropzone containing `classA` or `classB` is always the immediate parent of the dropped element. If it isn't you can always adjust the selector for `$dropzone` accordingly.

Comment: i am not using drop function of droppable instead using receive function of sortable because use of drop function cause multiple firing on dropping

Comment: Same works when i put your code in sortable receive function. Excellent solution. Thank you so much. I was stuck with it for a few days. Thanks dude